# Задача codeWars. Различия решений задачи JavaScript

Tags: javascript, классы, функции

Возникла проблема в решении задачи из codeWars. Сперва условие:

> Роутер должен принять бинды для данного url, http метод и действие. Затем, когда приходит запрос со связанным URL-адресом и методом, он должен вернуть результат действия. Пример:
>
> `var router = new Router;
>   router.bind('/hello', 'GET', function(){ return 'hello world'; });
>   router.runRequest('/hello', 'GET') // returns 'hello world';`
>   Когда запрашивается маршрут, который не существует, маршрутизатор должен вернуть: 'Error 404: Not Found'

В чём соль. Я написал вот такое решение:

```js
const Router = function() {
        this.firstArg = "";
        this.secondArg = "";
        this.funcArg;
        this.bind = function(url, method, action) {
          this.firstArg = url;
          this.secondArg = method;
          this.funcArg = action();
        };
        this.runRequest = function(url, method) {
          if (url != this.firstArg && method != this.secondArg) {
            return "Error 404: Not Found";
          } else {
            return this.funcArg;
          }
        };
      };
```

Но оно не работает. Решил поискать рабочее решение в интернете. Нашел вот это:

```js
class Router {
    
    constructor() {
        this.routes = new Map();
    }  
        
    bind(url, method, action) {
        this.routes.set(url + ":" + method, action);
    }
    
    runRequest(url, method) {
        if (!this.routes.has(url + ":" + method)) {
            return "Error 404: Not Found";
        }
        return this.routes.get(url + ":" + method)();
    }
    
}
```

Я не понимаю, в чем принципиальное различие между этими решениями? Да, тут класс. Да ,тут как я понял, создался ключ из url и method хранящий action. Но в конце концов оба подхода проводят проверку существует ли введенный запрос и выводит action или 'Error 404: Not Found' в противном случае. Объясните пожалуйста, почему мой подход не работает в таком случае

Comment: в вашем варианте привязать можно только один маршрут. что как-бы несколько странно для роутера. очевидно во втором варианте можно добавить N-ное число маршрутов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем варианте заключены несколько важных ошибок
1) Ваша реализация может сделать привязку только к одному адресу.

```
        this.bind = function(url, method, action) {
          this.firstArg = url;
          this.secondArg = method;
          this.funcArg = action();
        };
```

В приведённом приведённом примере из Интернета используется Map что бы задать множество пар (ключ - значение)

2) Вы сразу вызываете обработчик запроса при создании новой связи

```
this.funcArg = action();
```

Из этого вытекает следующая ошибка

3) Вы не вызываете обработчик при наступлении события и не возвращаете его результат. В примере из Интернета это строка

```
return this.routes.get(url + ":" + method)();
```